# How to convert this SQL query to XQuery?

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

How to convert this SQL query into the XQuery equivalent

```
SELECT e.essn AS one, f.essn AS two, e.pno, f.pno 
FROM works_on AS e JOIN works_on AS f on e.pno = f.pno 
AND e.essn < f.essn \n" . "ORDER BY `e`.`pno` ASC
```

I have tried this so far, but it does not give the desired results

```
let $prods := doc("../company/works_on.xml")//works_on[pno = $project/pnumber]
for $d in distinct-values($prods/essn),
$n in distinct-values($prods[essn = $d]/pno)
return <result essn="{$d}" pno="{$n}"/>
```

This is a sample of the XML file that I am using.

```
<dataroot>

    <works_on>

        <essn>123456789</essn>

        <pno>1</pno>

        <hours>32.5</hours>

    </works_on>

    <works_on>

        <essn>123456789</essn>

        <pno>2</pno>

        <hours>7.5</hours>

    </works_on>

    <works_on>

        <essn>333445555</essn>

        <pno>2</pno>

        <hours>10</hours>

    </works_on>

    <works_on>

        <essn>333445555</essn>

        <pno>3</pno>

        <hours>10</hours>

    </works_on>
```

This is the output so far

```
<results>
  <project>
    <pnumber>1</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>453453453</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>2</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
      <essn>453453453</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>3</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
      <essn>666884444</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>10</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
      <essn>987987987</essn>
      <essn>999887777</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>20</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
      <essn>888665555</essn>
      <essn>987654321</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>30</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>987654321</essn>
      <essn>987987987</essn>
      <essn>999887777</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
</results>
```

I'm trying to get the values for essn into pairs for example, on project 1, it will be as is, but for project 2, there will be 123456789 and 333445555 as one pair, 123456789 and 453453453 as another pair, and finally 333445555 and 453453453 as the final pair. They should be non repeating and non reversed pairs.

Comment: Readers will probably ask what you have tried. Could you add that in to your question? That will help them see what you are stuck on in particular.

Comment: Ok. i have added it

Comment: Great! Now, can you show a representative sample of `works_on.xml`, what your actual output is, and what you wanted instead? If you can do that promptly we can stop the question being put on hold (or we can vote to re-open it if it has already closed at that time).

Comment: Im done. i have added the additional information

Comment: Much better - thank you. It's not something I can help with, but someone else probably can.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: .. also which RDMS product are you using, as that SQL tag is not RDMS related..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided XML is cut for brevety (a good idea btw), but - which makes it a bit difficult to understand your issue - it is no more corresponding to your epected output.

At the moment I'm sitting in front of a SQL-Server, so the test code is T-SQL, but the idea of the XQuery should be the same with other engines:

--Your XML

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<dataroot>
  <works_on>
    <essn>123456789</essn>
    <pno>1</pno>
    <hours>32.5</hours>
  </works_on>
  <works_on>
    <essn>123456789</essn>
    <pno>2</pno>
    <hours>7.5</hours>
  </works_on>
  <works_on>
    <essn>333445555</essn>
    <pno>2</pno>
    <hours>10</hours>
  </works_on>
  <works_on>
    <essn>333445555</essn>
    <pno>3</pno>
    <hours>10</hours>
  </works_on>
</dataroot>';
```

--The T-SQL-Query with the embedded XQuery

```
SELECT @xml.query
('<results>
  {
  for $p in distinct-values(/dataroot/works_on/pno/text())
  order by $p
  return <project><pnumber>{$p}</pnumber>
         <employee>
         {
         for $e in distinct-values(/dataroot/works_on[pno=$p]/essn/text())
         order by $e
         return <essn>{$e}</essn>
         }
         </employee>
         </project>
  } 
  </results>')
```

The result (for the shortened XML)

```
<results>
  <project>
    <pnumber>1</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>2</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>123456789</essn>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
  <project>
    <pnumber>3</pnumber>
    <employee>
      <essn>333445555</essn>
    </employee>
  </project>
</results>
```

The idea in short:

We find a distinct list of project numbers and write out the main output structure with the project numbers. Internally we create the `<employee>` element and fill it with the `<essn>` values found **below any `<works_on>`**, which **has a `<pno>` as the current number**.

Hope this helps...